# Ng-class not evaluating the given argument

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I have a problem with the ng-class directive : i want to dynamically add a class when the screen size is large or medium. From what i can tell the condition is not being evaluated when generating the html or something like that because in the controller i see the correct value but the needed class is not added.

```
$scope.deviceLocal= $rootScope.devicee;
$rootScope.$on('size-changed', function(event, args) {
    $scope.deviceLocal = args.device;
});
```

and the html part

```
<label ng-class="{\'labelFloatRight\':deviceLocal == \'large\', \'labelFloatRight\':deviceLocal == \'medium\'}">
```

I escape the ' character because the label is inside a template formed with '.

Thanks,
Vio

Comment: did you try `$scope.$apply();` ?

Comment: Class name is same in both cases.

Comment: @SameerK should i try something like this : deviceLocal == 'large' || deviceLocal == 'medium' ?

Comment: @SameerK that was the problem it seems, please post your comment as an answer so that i can accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Class name is same in both cases. Change the class name according to `deviceLocal` value.